# Как показать скрытый div, когда он не рядом с input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}

input[id=on]:checked+.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="true" id="on">on</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="true" id="off">off</label>

<span>[on/off]</span>
<div class="block"> =[on]</div>
```

Без JavaScript нельзя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такой разметки - только JS. Но если её немного изменить и организовать собственные радио-кнопки, что-то, да получится)

```css
.invis { display: none; }

#off:checked ~ .show-off { display: block; }
#on:checked  ~ .show-on  { display: block; }

/* Ненужный декорасьон */

.radio { display: none; }

.custom-rad {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.lab {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-right: 2px solid #090;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lab:hover { color: #045acf; border-color: #045acf; }

#on:checked  ~ label .radio-on::after,
#off:checked ~ label .radio-off::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
  background-color: #070;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0a0, #080, #050)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="off" class="radio" type="radio" name="true">
  <input id="on"  class="radio" type="radio" name="true">

  <label for="on"  class="lab"><span class="custom-rad radio-on" ></span> on </label>
  <label for="off" class="lab"><span class="custom-rad radio-off"></span> off</label>

  <hr>

  <div class="invis show-on" >= [on] </div>
  <div class="invis show-off">= [off]</div>
</div>
```

P.s. ну и вместо собственных чекбоксов - в зависимости от отмеченности, евтевственно могут быть применены любые другие стили - подчеркивание, и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо большое, идея хороша, но я думаю лучше тогда через js , притом у меня в проекте 10+ input-ов, и каждый так описывать - это слишком